# http get returns 403

Tags: java, json, http, get

I'm trying to get some instant answer from the DuckDuckGo API, but I keep getting error 403. here is my code so far:

```
    static JSONObject getData(String term){
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject json = null;
    term = term.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

    try {
        URL ob=new URL("http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=" + term + "&format=json&pretty=0");
        HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection) ob.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("USER_AGENT", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())));
        json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(br.readLine());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
}
```

I can't seem to get it to work. I've read I need to identofy as a normal browser, but I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Any help with this?

Comment: I confirm. I got the same error. I am trying to debug it further.

Comment: I got through it without any errors. Now, I am trying to verify if the returned JSONObject has any data.

Comment: I put together some quick/dirty code that worked. I will post in few mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the 403 (same as you) with HttpURLConnection. But, it worked when I used URLConnection instead of HttpURLConnection. Because of quick availability, I just used org.json.simple parser. The json object printed the parsed data at the end.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

import org.json.simple.*;
import org.json.simple.parser.*;

public class HelloWorld{

  public static void main(String []args){

     try {
         JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
         JSONObject json = null;
         URL url = new URL("http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=science&format=json&pretty=0");
         URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
         conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB;     rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");

         Scanner scn = new Scanner(conn.getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\A");
         String buffer = scn.hasNext() ? scn.next() : "";
         json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(buffer);
         System.out.println(json.toString());

     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well that fixed the 403, so thanks for that, but how do I get actual info from it? All I can get it to say is http://pastebin.com/EsVv8JTh

Comment: @coolnickname, You have a parsed json object (it it like a Map/HashMap). You can access more info using it's methods. Isn't that what you were looking for? If you want to understand the output better, try pretty printing it (May be you can use any free site that pretty prints your one liner output).

Comment: As of 2017-03-21 still no metering/limits, but you now need to consistently identify your client to get results back... line below: 
`conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","ClientName");`
Must match the "&t=ClientName" parameter in the URL which includes.  Here's an example that worked for me from Java:
http://api.duckduckgo.com/?format=json&pretty=1&t=ClientName&q=Elephant+and+Castle

Without User-Agent got HTTP Error Code 500, with User-Agent and "t" param that don't match got HTTP 301 and blank HTML page telling me only that the page redirects to main. Also URLencode your "q" parameter